# How to change SweetAlert keyword from `swal` to 'swal2'

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Hi I've been using [SweetAlert](https://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) and I need the [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) chaining modals.

I don't want to remove **SweetAlert** because it is used vastly in our application. How can I change the keyword `swal` of **SweetAlert2** to `swal2` so that it will not collide with our current **SweetAlert** plugin?

So that I can have:

```
swal2('Sweet Alert 2');
```

Comment: `var swal2 = swal;` prior to loading `SweetAlert` but after loading `SweetAlert2` seems like it'd work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did and it works:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="swal">swal</button>
<button id="swal2">swal2</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@latest/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<script>
    var swal2 = swal;
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#swal').on('click', function() { swal('Hi from swal', 'success') })
    $('#swal2').on('click', function() { swal2('Hi from swal2') })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However, it only worked for me when I put ".fire" after swal2.
swal2.fire('Hi from swal2')